# 2 Windows 8 Loaders appearing at the grub menu

Tags: grub2, windows, xubuntu

So, after an install of Xubuntu, my grub loader has 3 things, Xubuntu and then 2 Windows 8 Loaders
How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install Xubuntu? What happens when you choose one or the other Windows entry? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

Install this software -> https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Edit the grub and delete the options you dont want.

Hope this helps..